# Is there a way to check if the Cryptsetup vulnerability patch is already installed?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptsetup

Is there a way to check if we already have the patch for the Cryptsetup vulnerability that's in the news recently?

http://hothardware.com/news/linux-vulnerability-found-by-holding-down-enter-key-for-70-seconds

I keep on getting software updates from the software center and I am not sure if one of those is for this specific vulnerability.

Thanks,

Comment: You can follow https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-4484.html.

Comment: @edwinksl Thanks for that link it is interesting. I found the "brute-force attack" classification  somewhat comical since it involves holding down the Enter key for 70 seconds.

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix: The attacker does not gain anything which they don't already have by obtaining physical access to the system. They get a single-user shell in the **initrd** environment. They can get that by booting the system from the installation media. There is nothing secret in the initial RAM file system.