# Test whether Ubuntu is vulnerable to (CVE-2016-4484)

Tags: security, root, vulnerability

I've been reading [this](http://thehackernews.com/2016/11/hacking-linux-system.html). Apparently I would gain root access if I hold down enter *(somewhere)* for 70 seconds. I tried it on a password prompt but it gave me like 3 attempts and stopped. I tried it on a tty but it didn't work also. Am I not vulnerable or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Do you have a LUKS encrypted disk?

Comment: I don't think so. I didn't really know what that is. (I googled it now quickly) @muru

Comment: ...so apparently I have to have such an encrypted disk to be vulnerable

Comment: That's the whole point. This vulnerability works on encrypted disks only, which is why this issue is so big

Comment: Similar to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/851064/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-cryptsetup-vulnerability-patch-is-already-install and it's original duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/563408/how-can-i-tell-if-a-cve-has-been-fixed-in-ubuntus-repositories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the security [website](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2016/CVE-2016-4484.html) from Canonical on this. All releases have a "needed" so there is no fix yet for them.

So if you match the conditions for this bug you can  affected. For 1 you need to be using *Linux Unified Key Setup* (LUKS), *cryptsetup*. So your partition needs to be using encryption. If you do not ... you do not have a problem. ([More info at hmarco.org](http://hmarco.org/bugs/CVE-2016-4484/CVE-2016-4484_cryptsetup_initrd_shell.html))

The fix is rather easy, just run this commands to add panic parameter to your boot configuration:

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="panic=5 /' /etc/default/grub grub-install
sudo grub-install
```

`panic=5` to your options preventing this problem. This is the number of seconds you want to initiate the reboot after the panic. Adding the `panic` parameter to the kernel entry in the grub configuration will prevent a shell.

Comment: Well, if you're not using encryption, you do have 99+ problems, but this ain't one. :P

Comment: During installation it asks whether I'd want the home folder encrypted, is that the encryption you're talking about?

Comment: Nope. It is about encryption for your boot disk.

Comment: okay, how do I know whether it's encrypted? XD

Comment: @MinaMichael during installation it asks if you want to use the whole disk with encryption (before the formatting stage)

Comment: If you don't know it is NOT encrypted ;-)

Comment: hehehe I see!

@muru okay I can't really remember :D

Comment: @MinaMichael see pic in point 4 here: http://www.tecmint.com/ubuntu-12-10-desktop-installation-guide-with-screenshots/

Comment: @muru yes that's the one I mean. but apparently this is not what makes me vulnerable right?

Comment: @MinaMichael no, that's the one. Home folder encryption is the option in pic 7.

Comment: @muru aaah I see! sadly I didn't encrypt any of my devices. too bad, I wanted to see it work. I'm evil X'D

Comment: install virtualbox and install an encrypted ubuntu in that.