# Help with CVE-2016-4484

Tags: grub2, sed

So there's this vulnerability from last year called CVE-2016-4484 that allows me to get a root shell by holding down the Enter key at bootup. It works on my computer (I've tried) I'm supposed to be able to just put the following code into the command line:

```
sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="panic=5 /' /etc/default/grub grub-install
```

However, that hasn't worked. I'm getting an error message:

```
sed: can't read grub-install: No such file or directory
```

I've already run `grub-install`. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Your `sed` command is invalid. Recheck your source and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at your command and checking out the issue description you linked, I'm pretty sure it has to be

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/&panic=5 /' /etc/default/grub
```

to edit the GRUB configuration and add the `panic=5` kernel option , followed by

```
sudo update-grub
```

to update the boot loader with the changed configuration.

Comment: That looks more like it.

Comment: @EndlessLight Well, if this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the grey check button on its left. That way you also mark your question as solved. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/851578/682481), I think you need to run the commands as root. Try the following:

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="panic=5 /' /etc/default/grub grub-install
sudo grub-install
```

Comment: This will still fail.

Comment: Your edit will still fail because of the `sed` command. And `grub-install` is not the correct command either.

Comment: @heynnema The edit didn't change the command. All I did was to add the link to the original (accepted) answer from Rinzwind (to what appears to be a very similar question asked last November). Sadly, my phone only allows me to have one question open at a time, so I had to copy & paste the code and the link to the question in 2 separate operations.

Comment: Yes, I saw that... but Rinzwind's answer is wrong too... which is surprising... but David did an edit 8 days later... so who knows where the error got introduced. Personally, if this was *my* answer, I'd delete it :-)